# Asynchronous thread-safe logging in C++ (no mutex)

Tags: c++, multithreading, logging, asynchronous, thread-safety

I'm actually looking for a way to do an asynchronous and thread-safe logging in my C++.

I have already explored thread-safe logging solutions like log4cpp, log4cxx, Boost:log or rlog, but it seems that all of them use a mutex. And as far as I know, mutex is a synchronous solution, which means that all threads are locked as they try to write their messages while other does.

Do you know a solution?

Comment: If you do not use mutex when writing to log file, it's possible that you get crashes or mixed logs, because your write accesses are simultaneous

Answer (score 6):

I think your statement is wrong: using mutex is not necessary equivalent to a synchronous solution.  Yes, Mutex is for synchronization control but it can be used for many different thing.  We can use mutex in, for example, a producer consumer queue while the logging is still happening asynchronously.

Honestly I haven't looked into the implementation of these logging library but it should be feasible to make a asynchronous appender (for log4j like lib) which logger writes to an producer consumer queue and another worker thread is responsible to write to a file (or even delegate to another appender), in case it is not provided.

---

Edit:
Just have had a brief scan in log4cxx, it does provide an AsyncAppender which does what I suggested: buffers the incoming logging event, and delegate to attached appender asynchronously.

Comment: +1 for highlighting the huge performance difference between locking a queue for the short time taken to push on a pointer/reference and locking over a complete disk write operation.

Answer (score 5):

I'd recomment avoiding the problem by using only one thread for logging. For passing the necessary data to log, you can use lock-free fifo queue (thread safe as long as producer and consumer are strictly separated and only one thread has each role -- therefore you will need one queue for each producer.)

Example of fast lock-free queue is included:

queue.h:

```
#ifndef QUEUE_H
#define QUEUE_H

template<typename T> class Queue
{
public:
    virtual void Enqueue(const T &element) = 0;
    virtual T Dequeue() = 0;
    virtual bool Empty() = 0;
};
```

hybridqueue.h:

```
#ifndef HYBRIDQUEUE_H
#define HYBRIDQUEUE_H

#include "queue.h"


template <typename T, int size> class HybridQueue : public Queue<T>
{

public:
    virtual bool Empty();
    virtual T Dequeue();
    virtual void Enqueue(const T& element);
    HybridQueue();
    virtual ~HybridQueue();

private:
    struct ItemList
    {
        int start;
        T list[size];
        int end;
        ItemList volatile * volatile next;
    };

    ItemList volatile * volatile start;
    char filler[256];
    ItemList volatile * volatile end;
};

/**
 * Implementation
 * 
 */

#include <stdio.h>

template <typename T, int size> bool HybridQueue<T, size>::Empty()
{
    return (this->start == this->end) && (this->start->start == this->start->end);
}

template <typename T, int size> T HybridQueue<T, size>::Dequeue()
{
    if(this->Empty())
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    if(this->start->start >= size)
    {
        ItemList volatile * volatile old;
        old = this->start;
        this->start = this->start->next;
            delete old;
    }
    T tmp;
    tmp = this->start->list[this->start->start];
    this->start->start++;
    return tmp;
}

template <typename T, int size> void HybridQueue<T, size>::Enqueue(const T& element)
{
    if(this->end->end >= size) {
        this->end->next = new ItemList();
        this->end->next->start = 0;
        this->end->next->list[0] = element;
        this->end->next->end = 1;
        this->end = this->end->next;
    }
    else
    {
        this->end->list[this->end->end] = element;
        this->end->end++;
    }
}

template <typename T, int size> HybridQueue<T, size>::HybridQueue()
{
    this->start = this->end = new ItemList();
    this->start->start = this->start->end = 0;
}

template <typename T, int size> HybridQueue<T, size>::~HybridQueue()
{

}

#endif // HYBRIDQUEUE_H
```

Comment: +1: a lock-free queue and a reader thread is indeed the way to go

Comment: What?  One queue for each producer - how is that to be managed?  How does this queue work anyway - what does the producer wait on when the queue is empty?   One logger thread , one P-C queue and a lock only around the queue push, (ie the queue is only locked for the time taken to push one object instance, (ie. 32/64 bit reference value), on, seems cleaner to me.

Comment: That! You can have vector or map of those queues, where you can assign queues to the threads, consumer just iterates over the whole array of queues. Producer doesn't wait, producer just enqueues more data :P Consumer can be put to sleep, do some other job, or OP can introduce some signaling mechanism on push, the class can be easily modified. As for the locking, OP wanted to avoid that.

Comment: Anyway, the locking mechanism can be easily introduced, but the code as it is can't support multiple producers pushing into one queue without just any locks. And the consumer going over the whole pool of queues introduces the fairness to the model.

Comment: Well, perhaps it's just me, but a queueing system that has to be managed on a per-thread basis seems very messy for the advantage of avoiding a possible lock over a queue push of a 32/64-bit item.  Using a condvar or semaphore to signal the consumer thread is going to be a kernel call anyway & the possible overhead of a contended lock is not going to make much difference.  IME, the OP wished to avoid trivial logging solutions where a mutex gets locked over a complete disk write operation, (whereupon the chance of contention is high).

Comment: I'm not disputing it, only noting what provided implementation is capable of and what is necessary to ensure the thread safety while using it as is. Should it be modified (which can be very easily done), the features/methods you mentioned can be applied. In any case, main idea behind it is still valid.

Answer (score 5):

If I get your question right you are concerned about doing I/O operation (probably write to a file) in a logger's critical section.

Boost:log lets you define a custom writer object. You can define operator() to call async I/O or pass a message to your logging thread (which is doing I/Os).

http://www.torjo.com/log2/doc/html/workflow.html#workflow_2b

Answer (score 2):

No libraries will do this as far as I know - it's too complex. You'll have to roll your own, and here's an idea which I just had, create a per thread log file, ensure that the first item in each entry is a timestamp, and then merge the logs after then run and sort (by timestamp) to get a final log file.

You can use some thread local storage may be (say a `FILE` handle AFAIK it won't be possible to store a stream object in thread local storage) and look this handle up on each log line and write to that specific file.

All this complexity vs locking the mutex? I don't know the performance requirements of your application, but if it is sensitive - why would you be logging (excessively)? Think of other ways to obtain the information you require without logging?

Also one other thing to consider is to use the mutex for the least amount of time possible, i.e. construct your log entry first and then just before writing to the file, acquire the lock.

Answer (score 1):

In a Windows program, we use a user-defined Windows message. First, memory is allocated for the log entry on the heap. Then PostMessage is called, with the pointer as the LPARAM, and the record size as the WPARAM. The receiver window extracts the record, displays it, and saves it in the log file. Then PostMessage returns, and the allocated memory is deallocated by the sender. This approach is thread-safe, and you don't have to use mutexes. Concurrency is handled by the message queue mechanism of Windows. **Not very elegant, but works.**

Comment: Does the windows message queue actually make guarantees about its concurrency handling scheme? I'd bet it's not lock-free.

Comment: It my, or may not, be lock-free.  More important, it's slow compared with any 'normal' user-space P-C queue, (eg. a queue with a CS protecting it and a semaphore for blocking).

Comment: OTOH, there is worse than a WMQ - a IOCP queue is even slower!  At least a WMQ is a better solution than a templated, (read as 'excessive and avoidable data copying'), lock-free queue per producer thread that all have to be polled by the consumer.

Comment: @MartinJames do the thinking before stating false facts (read as 'you can template a pointer to the structure')

Comment: @Erbureth - yes you can, of course, do that.  If I gave any other impression, then I did not mean to.  I will say, though, that some generic queue examples do not do so, keep locks for excessively long periods and increase contention.  In an OO language, one might well make the argument that generics are not necessary because all object references are the same size :)

Answer (score 1):

Lock-free algorithms are not necessarily the fastest ones. Define your boundaries. How many threads are there for logging? How much will be written in a single log operation at most?

I/O bound operations are much much slower than thread context switching due to blocking/awaking threads. Using lock-free/spinning lock algorithm with 10 writing threads will bring a heavy load to CPU.

Shortly, block other threads when you are writing to a file.

Comment: Shortly block other threads when you are pushing log entries onto a queue - even better.